# How do you use sftp with gedit on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, text-editors, sftp, gedit

Do you need a plugin to edit sftp files on a remote server with gedit? Which one works best?

What about (non-secure) ftp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you don't, you can mount the remote server (sftp or ftp) with nautilus to your local filesystem, then use gedit to edit them like ordinary local files.

Comment: You mean by adding a place?

Comment: @B Seven: Yes, or by simply accessing a `sftp://...` address from within Gedit.